# A few questions about using FourSquare API for a food truck

Tags: foursquare

I am currently working on tying in social media for a Food Truck client. I would like to be able to show food truck locations on a map and also be able to indicate the current location of the truck on the map. I have a few questions regarding this since I have never used FourSquare before.

- Can I create one "moving target" business and have them check in with that, or do I need to have them make a separate location for every location the food truck will be?
- Is there a way to distinguish a current location from past locations(i.e. can I include a parameter in the search query to display a different icon for a location if the food truck checked in within the past 30min-hour or something similar?)

Comment: Otherwise, a different approach would be if I could retrieve the most recent check-in of a specific user and then just have them check in to whatever location they are at with that user.

Comment: did you ever come up with a solution to this? I'm starting something similar.

Comment: Quite interested in this. Let me know if you got anywhere with it.